Angular with firebase Auth and SSR shows wrong component while Guard is resolving login status
I have an Angular (17.3.0) app with standalone components and using the @angular/fire library.
The App has 2 screens, a Home screen and a Login screen.
Expected Behaviour: When user tries to enter directly to localhost:4200/Home, check if he is logged in first. If he is, let him pass. If he is not, redirect to login page.
Actual Behaviour:User is logged in, enters directly to localhost:4200/Home and before this page renders, the login page is rendered briefly before the actual home page is rendered.
I attempted lots of things, filled the code with console.log and I don't seem to find why is this happening.
How can I avoid the rendering of the login page while the user is still being figured out by firebase?
Steps to reproduce it:

Make sure you have latest Angular version as of today (17.3.7)
ng new your-project (add SSR)
Add the following classes and dependencies needed. You'll need to provide your own firebase config data.
ng serve
Log in with Google.
Reload /home page, you'll see the login page for a second before the home page.

home.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from "../../services/auth.service";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  template: `<p>Welcome to the home page!</p>
             <button (click)="logout()">Log out</button>`,
  styleUrl: './home.component.sass'
})
export class HomeComponent {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {
  }
  logout() {
    this.authService.logout().then(() => this.router.navigateByUrl('login'))
  }
}


login.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from "../../services/auth.service";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  template: `<p>LOGIN</p>
             <button (click)="login()">Log in</button>`,
  styleUrl: './login.component.sass'
})
export class LoginComponent {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {

  }

  login() {
    this.authService.login().then(() => this.router.navigateByUrl('home'))
  }
}


app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet],
  template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
  styleUrl: './app.component.sass'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'guard-delay';
}


authService.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {firstValueFrom, Observable} from "rxjs";
import {Auth, authState, GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithPopup, signOut, User} from "@angular/fire/auth";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  private loggedIn: boolean | undefined = true;
  private user$: Observable<User | null>;
  constructor(private auth: Auth) {
    this.user$ = authState(auth)
  }

  async logout() {
    console.log('Loggin out')
    return signOut(this.auth)
  }

  async login(){
    return signInWithPopup(this.auth, new GoogleAuthProvider())
  }

  async isLoggedIn(){
    console.log('Checking if logged in')
    return firstValueFrom(this.user$).then(user => !!user)
  }
}

authGuard.ts
import {CanActivateFn, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {inject} from "@angular/core";
import {AuthService} from "../services/auth.service";

export const authGuard: CanActivateFn =  async (route, state) => {
  const authService: AuthService = inject(AuthService)
  const router: Router = inject(Router)
  const isLoggedIn =  await authService.isLoggedIn();
  return isLoggedIn ? true : router.createUrlTree(['login']);
};


app.routes.ts
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {HomeComponent} from "./components/home/home.component";
import {authGuard} from "./guards/auth.guard";
import {LoginComponent} from "./components/login/login.component";

export const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [authGuard]},
  {path:'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path:'', pathMatch:'prefix', redirectTo:'home'}
];


app.config.ts
import {ApplicationConfig, importProvidersFrom} from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import {connectAuthEmulator, getAuth, provideAuth} from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { getDatabase, provideDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export const firebaseConfig =  {
  apiKey: "<your config here>",
    authDomain: "<your config here>",
    databaseURL: "<your config here>",
    projectId: "<your config here>",
    storageBucket: "<your config here>",
    messagingSenderId: "<your config here>",
    appId: "<your config here>",
    measurementId: "<your config here>"
}
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes), provideClientHydration(), importProvidersFrom(
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(firebaseConfig)),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    provideDatabase(() => getDatabase()))]
};


I already tried different variations with observables and promises and all of them ended the same way. I tried to use mocked observables that take some seconds to finish and couldnt replicate the scenario, it only happened with the firebase sdk.
UPDATE
I found out that this happens when SSR is activated. Apparently, SSR comes enabled by default in the development build configuration which is used in the serve build. If I disable SSR the problem stops reproducing itself. I would like to understand what's going on if anybody can help me out.
Here is my angular.json:
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "guard-delay": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "sass"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/guard-delay",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "sass",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.sass"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "server": "src/main.server.ts",
            "prerender": true,
            "ssr": {
              "entry": "server.ts"
            }
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "guard-delay:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "guard-delay:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "guard-delay:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "sass",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.sass"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


Removing this SSR configuration, the problem stops.
            "prerender": true,
            "ssr": {
              "entry": "server.ts"
            }

Is this a bug of firebase with SSR or I'm misusing the SSR feature?

I have the same issue with Angualr 18. The "signInWithPopup" did not work with the same error, and removing
"prerender": true,
"ssr": {
    "entry": "server.ts"
}

magically solved the issue.
